# Installing Ubuntu Server fails to detect SATA CD/DVD Drive

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sata, optical-media

- O/S: Ubuntu 8.04 Server LTS 64-bit
- Drive: Lite-On SATA CD/DVD Burner, DS-8A4S
- Motherboard: Supermicro x8ste

Booting from the CD/DVD works fine, but the installer fails to detect the drive with the error:

```
No common CD-ROM drive was detected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the x8ste BIOS, configure SATA#1 to use AHCI instead of IDE Enhanced, and it will properly detect both CD/DVD and system drives.

Comment: Worked like a charm on an HP Proliant DL 380 G8 Server, while trying to install Debian.

Answer (score 1):

No definitive answer, but two thoughts here:

1. You should look at the kernel messages when Ubuntu is booting and see if the system sees the disk controller or the disks attached to it. Based on the Super Micro motherboard/OS compatibility chart at http://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/OS/C7_X8.cfm I'm skeptical.
2. It's true that Ubuntu 8.04 is the LTS version, but it's also true that it's two years old. It's not uncommon for old distributions to fail on newer hardware. You might want to give the 10.04 beta a try -- true, it's only a beta, but it's the next LTS version. I think odds are good that 10.04 (or possibly even one of the 9.* versions) will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  According to that chart, Ubuntu 8.04 64-bit is compatible with the x8ste under ide "enhance" mode.  I'm looking for this under BIOS settings presently.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+ALT+F4, look at mounting cdrom, and note path to cdrom, for me /dev/sr0, and in the installation when proposing to enter de path after fail of detectiong cdrom, enter the path what u ve note and let's go.